# How to setup Autofac registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, autofac

Im new to dependency injection and Ive decided to use autofac as it seems to have the best 'out of the box' support for MVC5 (others might be better but im a newbie to this)

Im creating simple use scenarios and from the wiki ive got the following code in `application_start` in `global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterType<ArtistController>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<ArtistService>().As<IArtistService>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<ArtistRepository>().As<IArtistRepository>().SingleInstance();
    builder.RegisterType<BandMemberRepository>().As<IBandMemberRepository>).SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));



    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
 }
```

and in my `ArtistController`  I have this

private `IArtistService _artistService`;

I then have some code the retrieves and updates data, all very simple. This works ok and Im starting to get my head around the whole concept.

My question is this, do I have to register all the concrete classes Im using manually ?  My app could eventually grow and I would have many, many classes so this will be a pain to manage.  I did come across this

```
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
```

which as far as Im aware should register everything for me but it didnt work.  Am I doing something wrong ?

---

ok, thanks for the advice.

the autofac website  shows an example using lambdas, so I added this in global.asax

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

but that didnt work, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I do most (90+%) of my registrations by tagging them with this attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
[JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUse]
public class AutoRegisterAttribute : Attribute {}
```

Then I use this module to register those classes:

```cs
public class AutoRegisterModule : Module
{
    private readonly Assembly[] _assembliesToScan;

    public AutoRegisterModule(params Assembly[] assembliesToScan)
    {
        _assembliesToScan = assembliesToScan;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assembliesToScan)
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<AutoRegisterAttribute>(false) != null)
            .AsSelf()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

    public static AutoRegisterModule ForCallingAssembly()
    {
        return new AutoRegisterModule(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
    }
}
```

So when I'm building my container, I typically just do:

```cs
builder.RegisterModule(AutoRegisterModule.ForCallingAssembly());
```